# Google Contact API throws error

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, google-contacts-api

We are trying to create and update contact from our application to Google.
But sometimes it throws

```
Error occured while creating contacts in Google[Line 41, Column 8, element id] ID must have a value
```

This is the stack trace generated:

```
com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.throwParseException(XmlParser.java:722)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:685)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:568)
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:838)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:1896)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.batch(Service.java:1373)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.batch(GoogleService.java:756)
```

Because of this bulk of contacts gets failed.

Please tell me what this issue is about.

```
try{
             if(createContact.getId() == null)
                {
                 System.out.println("Inside_create_of_update");
                    BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(createContact, BatchOperationType.INSERT);
                    BatchUtils.setBatchId(createContact,"create");
                    updateFeed.getEntries().add(createContact);
                }
                else
                {
                    //If contact already present in google with this email, we just update this
                    //instead of creating new contact
                    System.out.println("Inside_update_of_update");
                    BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(createContact, BatchOperationType.UPDATE);
                    BatchUtils.setBatchId(createContact,"update");
                    updateFeed.getEntries().add(createContact);
                }
                updateRequestCount++;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception occured while updating contact:"+e);
            }
        }

        if (updateRequestCount >= 95 || ((i >= (contacts.size() - 1) && updateRequestCount != 0)))
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Inside batch update");
            responseFeed = contactService.batch(new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch?"
                + "access_token=" + token), updateFeed);
            System.out.println("Response_feed"+responseFeed);
            for(int v=0;v<responseFeed.getEntries().size();v++)
            {
                ContactEntry entry = responseFeed.getEntries().get(v);
                String batchId = BatchUtils.getBatchId(responseFeed.getEntries().get(v));
                IBatchStatus status = BatchUtils.getStatus(entry);
```

Comment: Where is your stack trace?

Comment: Error occured while creating contacts in Google[Line 41, Column 8, element id] ID must have a value.  We could get only this inspite of printing whole stacktrace

Comment: Hi, I didnt hear back from you. This is kind of urgent issue. Please reply asap.

Comment: does anybody else have any idea related to this. This is really bothering me.